# Answering older questions

Tags: discussion

I'm relatively new to stackexchange.  Although I've searched it for answers many times, I've only rarely contributed.

My question is:  should we answer older questions?  How old does a question have to be before it should be considered "expired"?

In my case, I just answered one that was 1.5 weeks old.  I wondered if I was wasting my time or not.

Answer (score 10):

Absolutely make an effort to answer old questions. Stack Exchange even rewards you with [a bronze](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/help/badges/64/revival) and [a silver](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/help/badges/17/necromancer) badge for such an achievement.

Questions don't expire. Even if the asker has long-sense departed, the majority of the beneficiaries of your answers will always be the future visitors to the site.

Great job for answering an old question already.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, a question that is only a week or two old, isn't very old.  And like drs pointed out, you even get badges for answering much older questions.

If you feel you have an answer that will fit in an old question answer it.  Even if it has answers, if your answer covers some aspect that wasn't covered or you put together a much more comprehensive one, more power to you.  This site is intending to collect great, correct answers, not give an answer to one individual.