# Are questions that may go out of date acceptable?

Tags: discussion

I'd like to ask about alternatives to SawStop. A correct answer to this may change in the coming years.

Is this acceptable?

If so, should I make my question time-specific? (Are there any alternatives as of April 2015?)

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't sound like the question will go out of date, but the answers might.  In 3 years if someone finds it they can add updated info or a whole new answer.

Comment: That's how SO works at least. Should be no different here

Answer (score 2):

As bowlturner and Matt mentioned, it is perfectly acceptable to add new answers to old questions, as was discussed in [Answering older questions](https://woodworking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114/answering-older-questions). Questions can remain relevant long into the future, even as the best answer changes over time.

If you ask about alternatives to SawStop, be very clear about what kinds of alternatives you would consider acceptable (or unacceptable) or else the answers will be very subjective. For many people, alternatives could range from "Use push sticks" to "Don't put your hand in the blade, stupid" or even "Most table saw injuries are caused by kickback so a SawStop won't help you anyway."

Comment: "Don't put your hand in the blade, stupid". Ha! I'll be sure to specify.